# SQL SERVER -- YEAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
Select (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())+(Select('-'))+(SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())+1));
```

I want output as `"2018-2019"`.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(GETDATE()), '-', YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1)
```

[CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) takes care of conversion to string, so you don't have to worry about that.

edit: Unfortunately I have been made aware that CONCAT is only available in sql server 2012 and higher.

Comment: `concat` is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @GSerg, damn, well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use + to append string since you are working with `SQL 2008`, higher version has `CONCAT()` function :

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' - ' + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `datename()`:

```
select (datename(year, getdate()) + '-' + datename(year, dateadd(year, 1, getdate()))
```

That way, you don't have to deal with converting integers to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
       '-' + 
       CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4))
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(Year,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
       '-' + 
       CAST(DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) + 1 AS VARCHAR(4))
```